# Any quick way to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a big matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When I was solving linear differential equation systems, I encountered a big matrix as coefficient. The matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & -3 & 0 & 1\\
-5 & 1 & -4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors step by step based on the definition just kills me. Is there any trick or strategy of solving problems like this?
Moverever, after I find the eigenvectors, and construct a matrix $\textbf{P}$ of eigenvectors, its inverse $\textbf{P}^{-1}$ is also difficult to compute. Any trick here?
After working for several minutes, I ended up with the diagonal eigenvalue matrix
$$\textbf{D}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&3&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the corresponding eigenvector matrix is
$$\textbf{P}=\begin{pmatrix}
2&-1&-2&-8&0\\
-10&1&1&15&0\\
-5&1&2&10&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
3&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
What if now I need to calculate $\textbf{x}=\textbf{P}e^{\textbf{D}t}\textbf{P}^{-1}\textbf{x}_0$, where $\textbf{x}_0$ is any constant vector.

Comment: Trick: there's a row of $0$s. This tells us the matrix is not invertible and hence $0$ is an eigenvalue!

Answer (score 1):

This will just use determinant of a $(3 \times 3)$ matrix as,

$det\begin{pmatrix}
1-t & 2 & -3 & 0 & 1\\
-5 & 1-t & -4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 4-t & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1-t & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0-t
\end{pmatrix}$ = $(-t)det\begin{pmatrix}
1-t & 2 & -3 & 0\\
-5 & 1-t & -4 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 4-t & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1-t \\
\end{pmatrix}$ = $(-t)(-(1-t))det\begin{pmatrix}
1-t & 2 & -3\\
-5 & 1-t & -4\\
0 & -2 & 4-t\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Then just solve as you do for a $(3\times 3)$ matrix.

Comment: I actually did what you said, and I edit my question. Can you check again? Thanks.